# How to chain multiple routes with Zend_Controlle

Tags: php, zend-framework, router, chain, undefined-index

My question is how to chain multiple routes using Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Chain?

For example I want to chain 3 routes for year/month/day
but the gole is:

```
when url is
example.com/2011
runs index controller, year action

example.com/2011/11
runs index controller, year-month action

example.com/2011/11/10
runs index controller, year-month-day action
```

I'm trying to use this code:

```
$front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$router = $front->getRouter();
$chain = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Chain();

$route1 = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    ':year',
    array(
        'controller' => 'news',
        'action'     => 'year'
    )
);

$route2 = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    ':month',
    array(
        'controller' => 'news',
        'action'     => 'year-month'
    )
);

$route3 = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    ':day',
    array(
        'controller' => 'news',
        'action'     => 'year-month-day'
    )
);

$chain->chain($route1)
      ->chain($route2)
      ->chain($route3);

$router->addRoute('chain', $chain)
       ->addRoute('route3', $route3)
       ->addRoute('route2', $route2)
       ->addRoute('route1', $route1);
```

When I go to example.com/2012 and example.com/2012/11/11 everything is OK

but when i visit example.com/2012/11/ application shows me year-month-day action and on page there is

```
Notice: Undefined index: day in P:\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Controller\Router\Route.php on line 299
```

Perhaps I am doing something wrong. Please, help me to solve my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the "undefined index" notice shows up because you haven't given the router any default values for year, month, and day.

One idea for a solution is using only one route, to match every request, using default values, e.g. 0. Then, in your controller, if "day" has a default value (day==0), you show the entire month etc.

```
$route1 = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    ':year/:month/:day',
    array(
        'controller' => 'news',
        'action'     => 'year',
        'year' => '0',
        'month' => '0',
        'day' => '0'
    )
);
```